# Installing Xampp on ubuntu 13.04 64-bits

Tags: installation, server, laptop, xampp

Can any one can help me installing Xampp server from http://www.apachefriends.org/ in to my ubuntu 13.04 64-bit desktop version plzz

Comment: it looks like a dupe indeed, but the answer below has fairly good potential and the answers in the dupe are a bit so and so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Get the tar file using wget

   `wget http://www.apachefriends.org/download.php?xampp-linux-1.7.3a.tar.gz`
2. Extract the tar file as

   `tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.7.3a.tar.gz -C /opt`
3. Give permissions

   `sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/`
4. Start xampp using

   `/opt/lampp/lampp start`
5. Stop xampp using

   `/opt/lampp/lampp stop`

Comment: I have just installed ubuntu 13 but I can't extract xampp to /opt due to permissions... I can't change /opt folder. any help please?

Comment: Use `sudo tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.7.3a.tar.gz -C /opt`

Comment: Never give 777 permission to htdocs, ever. Rather try `chown`ing the directory.